# Occasional disk I/O errors in SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a very simple website running PHP and SQLite 3.7.9 (with PDO).

After establishing the SQLite connection I immediately execute the following queries:

```
PRAGMA busy_timeout=0;
PRAGMA cache_size=8192;
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
PRAGMA journal_size_limit=67110000;
PRAGMA legacy_file_format=OFF;
PRAGMA page_size=4096;
PRAGMA recursive_triggers=ON;
PRAGMA secure_delete=ON;
PRAGMA synchronous=NORMAL;
PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY;
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint=4096;
```

This website only has one writer and a few occasional readers, so I don't expect any concurrency problems (and I'm even using WAL). Every couple of days, I've seen this error being reported by PHP:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message '**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error**' in ... Stack trace: #0 ...: PDO->exec('**PRAGMA cache_si...**')

There are several things that make this error very weird to me:

- it's not a transient problem - no matter how many times I refresh the page, it won't go away
- the database file is not corrupted - the sqlite3 executable can open the database without problems

If the following pragmas are commented out, PHP stops throwing the disk I/O exception:

```
PRAGMA cache_size=8192;
PRAGMA synchronous=NORMAL;
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
```

Then, after successfully reconnecting to the database, I'm able to reintroduce these pragmas and the code with run smoothly for days - until eventually, the same error will occur without any apparent reason. I wasn't able to reproduce this error so far, so I'm clueless about the origin of it.

I'm really curious what may be causing this problem... Any ideas?

*Environment*:

- Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS
- PHP 5.4.15
- SQLite 3.7.9

  - Database size: ≃ 10MiB
  - Transaction (write) size: ≃ 1KiB

---

**EDIT**: Might these symptoms have something to do with [`busy_timeout`](http://blogs.perl.org/users/timm_murray/2013/02/sqlite-and-writes.html)?

Comment: What file system? Any VM?

Comment: Thanks for replying @CL. Yes. Ext4 on OpenVZ. Does the VM affect anything? If so, what can I do to minimize the risk of this happening (besides moving to a dedicated server)?

Comment: Try disabling WAL mode. (You should then also set busy_timeout.)

Comment: @CL.: WAL is really necessary in this case. However, I'm interested in knowing your rationale. Also, please consider the following: temporarily removing the pragmas I mentioned above makes the error go away, even though the WAL mode is persistent between connections - so I figure the `journal_mode` is not the culprit here?

Comment: @CL.: As for the `busy_timeout`, I've increased it to `1000` - not sure if this is an appropriate value or how it can affect other connections, but the error hasn't showed up since.

Comment: OpenVZ does not virtualize the disk hardware like a 'real' VM, so `fsync` should be implemented correctly. I suspect that OpenVZ does something wrong with shared memory (used by WAL). `busy_timeout` is needed if WAL is actually disabled.

Comment: This behavior happens to me when the disk is full. Cleaning the disk enables me to open the sqlite file again in WAL mode.